# django allauth not working on production

Tags: django, django-allauth

I can't login or signup on my production server. Configuration is same for local and development server. I used same settings for both of them, same requirements installed in order to identify what's wrong but no hope.

```
python manage.py check
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

some of related configuration

```
SITE_ID = 1

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('amazon_advertising:home')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('account_login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('account_logout')

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

I can login and logout django admin panel but django allauth login do not work. There is no error just waiting in response.

on production server I run it with

```
python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I tried nginx+gunicorn same problem exists.

Login view is successfully parsed with my custom template but can not login or signup.

Edit: If I give wrong credentials in login it response me perfectly with "The login and/or password you specified are not correct." but if credentials are right nothing happens.

Comment: You may want to add the add the view part of the login so we can have more details.

Comment: actually I don't have view part I just added    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')) . It works like a charm in local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it.
When made ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional" 
I successfully logged in.
That was the superuser created from `python manage.py createsuperuser` which not automatically verify email.